# Where to configure custom zone for sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, iis7

How can I configure the custom zone for Sharepoint 2013? I need to update the Host header, port ,authentication provider and SSL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For custom zone you need to extend the webapplication eq:-

Extending your Web Application

- Go to Central Administration- Application Management-Manage Web
  Application -Select the Web Application -Go to Ribbon - Extend.
- In the Create a new IIS website section, give the Web Application a
  name. Give the required port.
- If you have https enabled, select Yes in Use Secure Socket Layer
  section.
- In the next section, choose your type of authentication, which you
  want to use for this zone.
- Now, click on save.

[And for Configuring SSL for SharePoint 2013
Refer link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fabdulwahab/2013/01/20/configure-ssl-for-sharepoint-2013/)